# Undefined offset: -1 PDO in for loop

Tags: php, mysql

I use pdo to connect mysql database and with PDO::FETCH_ASSOC function .. fetch ASSOC array..

But when run the code give this error in multi lines.

> Undefined offset: -1 or Undefined offset: 61

```
if($pays[$i]['price'] < $pays[($i-1)]['price'])
```

and

```
elseif($pays[$i]['price'] > $pays[($i-1)]['price'])
```

and

`.$pays[$i]['price'].`

My full code

```
<?php

$params        = null; //or any params
$mrkfPDO       = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=usd', 'root', '', array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
));
$mrkfStatement = $mrkfPDO->prepare("SELECT price FROM uds limit 0,100");
$mrkfStatement->execute($params);
$pays = $mrkfStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

for ($i = 0; $i <= count($pays); $i++) {

    $color = 'black';

    if ($pays[$i]['price'] < $pays[($i - 1)]['price'])
        $color = "red";
    elseif ($pays[$i]['price'] > $pays[($i - 1)]['price'])
        $color = 'green';
    else
        $color = 'black';

    echo "<tr>
                        <td>
                            <span style='color: $color'>" . $pays[$i]['price'] . "</span>
                        </td>
                      </tr>";
}

?>
```

Comment: due to `$i = 0 in your for loop` you got that error. start `$i  =1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `$i = 0`. first time `$i = 0` hens `$pays[($i-1)]['price']` gives `-1` index which is always an offset error. Do like below :-

```
for($i=1; $i<count($pays); $i++) // see the change
```

Answer (score 1):

You loop

```
        for($i=0; $i<=count($pays); $i++)
```

starts at `$i=0`.

Then you try this:

```
          if($pays[$i]['price'] < $pays[($i-1)]['price'])
```

There is a `$pays[($i-1)]`. That is your unknown index `-1 ($i-1 (or 0-1 for the first loop))`